# Aggregate: Seed with a null value

Tags: c#, aggregate

I am trying to find some items, then get the closest one by vector distance. Sometimes `FindAll` doesn't return elements causing `Aggregate` to fail. I could check to see that the list does in fact contain something, but could I just seed the `Aggregate` with some value such as `null` somehow? I tried using null, but I get this error:

> The type arguments for method 'Enumerable.Aggregate(IEnumerable, TAccumulate, Func)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.

Is there a way to run aggregate so that it returns either `AIBrain` or `null`?

```
public AIBrain Closest(AIAttack attack = null) {
  if (others.Count == 0) return null;
  return others
    .FindAll(item => attack != null ? attack.IsAttackable(item) : true)
    .Aggregate(null, (curr, item) => {
      float currDistance = Vector3.Distance(transform.position, curr.transform.position);
      float itemDistance = Vector3.Distance(transform.position, item.transform.position);
      return itemDistance < currDistance ? item : curr;
    });
}
```

Comment: Cast the `null` value that you are passing in to `Aggregate` as the 1st argument. Example: `null as float?`

Comment: @Igor Well `(AIBrain)null` should be enough.

Comment: Well... that seems easier than I thought...

Comment: Haha sometimes the solution is simple! @Igor should write that as an answer unless there's a dupe for null casting and generic type arguments.

Comment: Found a dupe, it's basically the same thing.